# Creating a Vaadin-sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, vaadin

I'd like to create a Vaadin project using sbt 0.11.0. I looked at the [sbt-vaadin-plugin](https://github.com/Gekkio/sbt-vaadin-plugin) and the [vaadin-skeleton](https://github.com/Gekkio/vaadin-skeleton) but both of them seem to be out of date. So, has anyone some tips on how to configure such a project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is two projects that use sbt 0.11 and Vaadin:

https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/incubator/scala-wrappers/

https://github.com/henrikerola/scala-addressbook

The first link is a project called scala-wrappers that tries to make easier to use Vaadin with Scala. The second link is a simple project that uses scala-wrappers.

Comment: Thanks a lot - exactly what I was looking for. Do you plan on taking the wrappers project outside the incubator and publish it anywhere?

Comment: So can you please tell me how to run the scala-addressbook in Eclipse or from sbt?

Comment: Added README to the github project that explains how to run the application.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a skeleton a while ago to use vaadin and sbt 0.7.

https://github.com/jaimefjorge/scala-java-lift-vaadin-project

You can update the configuration to 0.11 using this [guide](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Migrating-from-SBT-0.7.x-to-0.10.x)